# Cargar fecha y hora actual al seleccionar opción de DropDownList - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera saber si es posible que al momento de seleccionar una opción de mi combo, se me auto-llene un `label` con **fecha y hora actual**.

Tengo dos `label`, uno se va auto-llenar al momento de seleccionar **estatus 1**, y el siguiente `label` se va auto-llenar al seleccionar el **estatus 2**.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, y mas que nada que esto que pretendo explicar, se pueda hacer, no se si con validaciones de JavaScript, no tengo la menor idea por donde empezar

así esta mi **Vista**

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstatusIdH)<span id="estatusReceta" class="text-danger">Requerido</span></label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstatusIdH, new SelectList(ViewBag.Estatus, "EstatusId", "Descripcion"), "Seleccionar", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstatusIdH, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y este es mi control de fecha y hora que quiero que se auto-llene

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Hora entrega programada:</label>
                    <input type="datetime-local" id="horaEntregaProgramada" class="form-control"
                           min="2019-11-07T00:00" max="2050-06-14T00:00">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controlador**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AsignacionFarmacias(string elegibilidad)
        {
            List<RecetasParaAsignar> lista = new List<RecetasParaAsignar>();
            lista = await ObtenerRecetasParaAsigna(elegibilidad);

            ViewBag.Asignar = lista;
            ViewBag.Elegibilidad = elegibilidad;

            ViewBag.Estatus = await this.ObtenerEstatusCombo();
            ViewBag.Farmacias = await this.ObtenerFarmaciaCombo();
            return View();
        }
```

**Modelo**

```
 namespace Vitamedica.Farmacias.Entidades
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EstatusCombo
    {
        public int EstatusId { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Método**

```
  public async Task<List<EstatusCombo>> ObtenerEstatusCombo()
        {
            try
            {
                EstatusCombo objPeticion = new EstatusCombo();
                List<EstatusCombo> ListaRecetas = new List<EstatusCombo>();
                using (var ClienteServicio = new HttpClient())
                {
                    ClienteServicio.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URLServiciosWeb"].ToString());

                    ClienteServicio.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    ClienteServicio.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    string peticion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objPeticion);

                    HttpResponseMessage respuesta = await ClienteServicio.PostAsync("api/recetas/consulta/estatus",
                        new StringContent(peticion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                    if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Stream streamContent = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        streamContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(streamContent))
                        {
                            ListaRecetas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EstatusCombo>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }

                    }
                }

                return ListaRecetas;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pudrías indicar en la pregunta el **Modelo** que pasas a la Vista y el código del **Controlador**. Sobre todo donde cargas el `ViewBag.Estatus`.

Comment: Bro, si estás iniciando con ASPnet MVC 5, este workshop te ayudará https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY cubre varios conceptos.

Comment: Listo Rafael agregue un poco mas de mi código

Comment: gracias fedyfx le echare un vistazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para detectar cualquier cambio en la selección de los elementos de tu `<select />` (`@Html.DropDownListFor()`), debes utilizar **jQuery**, y mas en concreto el método **`$().change()`**.

Una vez capturado el evento compruebas cual a sido **el valor seleccionado**, y en función de este, asignas la fecha actual al `<input />`.

El código **script** jQuery sería el siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#EstatusIdH").change(function () {
            // SI EL VALOR SELECCIONADO ES 1, ASIGNA LA FECHA ACTUAL AL INPUT
            if ($("#EstatusIdH option:selected").val() == 1) {
                $("#horaEntregaProgramada").val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,16));
            }                                
        });
    });
</script>
```

**NOTA:** Ten en cuenta que si estás utilizando un proyecto estándar ASP.NET MVC de Visual Studio con página maestra (`_Layout.cshtml`), debes incluir el script dentro dentro de la sección **`@section scripts { ... }`** de tu Vista.

---

**UPDATE**: 
`date.toJSON ()` imprime la fecha UTC en una cadena formateada como json-date.

Si deseas que se imprima tu hora local, debes usar `getTimezoneOffset()`, que devuelve el desplazamiento en minutos. Debes convertir este valor en segundos y agregarlo a la marca de tiempo de tu fecha:

```
var date = new Date();
$("#horaEntregaProgramada").val(new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toJSON().slice(0,16));
```

Comment: Si funciona, solo hay un detalle, que no me carga la hora actual, todo lo demas si funciona

Comment: @DavidCopca: Yo he probado el ejemplo y si trae la hora actual. Todo va en función del método `slice(0,16)` que captura en este caso hasta 16 posiciones en la fecha obtenida. Prueba a aumentar el 16 a 19 para que te tome 3 posiciones mas.

Comment: ya lo intente, pero solo seta los segundos, y lo que no me setea bien es la hora y el am o pm, porque los minutos si carga los correctos

Comment: @DavidCopca: Entonces que hora te carga? está mal la hora?. Ten en cuenta que la hora cargada es la del **CLIENTE** y en formato 24H sin PM ni AM. Simplemente se ajusta al formato que tienes en el input `type="datetime-local"`

Comment: Un ejemplo si son las 11:10 a.m; me carga 05:10 p.m.

Comment: Hora actual amigo, 11:16 a.m.

Comment: @DavidCopca He editado la respuesta, revísala a ver si te funciona así.

Comment: Funciono a la perfección amigo, muchas gracias